# Out do I concatenate the beginning of an array subscript of a substring and the end substring

Tags: powershell

```
$getRead = @($readFile)

for($i = 0; $i -lt getRead.length; $i++){
    $getEnd = $readFile.substring(readFile[$i].length - 1, 4)
    $getStart = $readFile.substring(readFile[$i].length 1, $getEnd)

    #$findMatchREGEX = "[0-8]"
    #$replaceWithREGEX = "9"

    #$newNum = $readFile -replace $findMatchREGEX,$replaceWithREGEX

}
```

I am reading in drivers license numbers of varying lengths for all 50 states. I need to change the last 4 digits to `9`
How do I get the beginning portion of the subscript in an array and then concatenate them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work provided you have a single driver's license number, per line in you file:

```
$readFile = "c:/path/file"
$getRead = gc $readFile

foreach ($line in $getRead){
    $getStart = $line.substring(0, $line.Length - 5)
    $resultWithNines = $getStart + "9999"
    echo $resultWithNines 
}
```

Comment: ` $getStart = $line.substring(0, $line.Length - 5)` ohhh okay this makes sense. thank you